# iOS8 Custom Keyboard View Loading Management

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I'm building a Custom Keyboard

As Apple recommends, I am customizing my keyboard UI in the `viewDidLoad` method

The problem is that my keyboard seems to stutter every time it's loaded

Do you know of any best practices to manage loading of keyboard views?

Thanks!

Comment: This happens to me too! I moved everything to `viewDidAppear` and I still had the stutter... I think it's just for debugging purposes right now, stutter will probably vanish in iOS8 GM release

Comment: When I run the same custom keyboard in a normal UIViewController - it works like magic. Looks like Apple's view loading is flawed.

Comment: If that's the case, then think you can rest assured that your loading will run smoothly in iOS8GM :) Until then just ignore it!

Comment: Hey! Just checking up, have you been able to find a solution in iOS8 Beta5? If not I am still waiting until GM... haven't tested moving everything to `viewDidAppear` in BETA5, have you?